# Is there a way to intentionally mangle the current Python namespace?

Tags: python, namespaces

I'm looking for a way to move several python files in to a single file e.g.
Instead of two files

foobartest.py

`from foo import *
bar()`

foo.py

`def bar()
    return 'foobar'`

Doing something like this:

`class foo():
    def bar()
#insert some way to get the class into the namespace
bar()`

Is there a way to get a locally defined class into the root namespace of the same script?

The reason is that I want to merge several files without having change all bar() calls to foo.bar() and still have it relatively obvious how they're broken up for someone reading the code.

edit: In the interest of clarity, I was looking for a way to do it for all functions in the class as opposed to individually for each function.  Like a way to do a wild import on a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds super hacky, but you can do something like

```
>>> class A:
    def x():
        pass
    def y():
        pass


>>> globals().update(A.__dict__)
>>> x
<function x at 0x02AF1CB0>
>>> y
<function y at 0x022D8230>
>>>
```

Comment: It is really hacky.  I'm keeping them separate for personal use and on github, but I wanted to slap them in a single python file to shove inside a C executable.

Answer (score 2):

If `foo.bar()` is a [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) or [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod), you could set `bar = foo.bar` at the top of the merged file. For example:

```
class foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        # ...

bar = foo.bar
bar() # calls foo.bar()
```

Comment: This would work.  I would just have to add a substantial amount of declarations to do it.  If I were going to do this, I might as well change calls to foo.bar().  Still helpful though.